# Proof of Equivalent Definitions of Wedge Product

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, tensors, differential-forms, exterior-algebra

I would like to show these two definitions of wedge product (of differential $k$ and $l$ forms are equivalent). The first definition is:

$$(\alpha \wedge \beta)(v_1, \cdots, v_{k+l}) = \frac{1}{k! l!} \sum_\sigma \text{sgn}(\sigma) \, \alpha(v_{\sigma(1)}, \cdots, v_{\sigma(k)}) \, \beta (v_{\sigma(k+1)}, \cdots, v_{\sigma(k+l)})$$

I.e this specifies the action of the wedge product on $k + l$ vectors. The other definition I have is this:

If we let $I$, $J$ denote $k$,$l$ multi-indices, and write:

$$
\alpha= \sum_{I}a_I  dx_I, \qquad \beta  = \sum_{J} b_J  dx_J
$$
Then the wedge product is given by:

$$
\alpha \wedge \beta = \sum_{IJ}a_I b_J dx_I \wedge dx_J
$$

I am not sure where to begin proving this, mainly because one definition only specifies what occurs when one evaluates the form.

Comment: Well, use the second definition and evaluate on $k+\ell$ vectors.

Comment: Ok, thank you. That direction seems fine. What about proving the equivalence of the second with the first? I assume I would have to provide some uniqueness argument.

Comment: I'm confused about "equivalence." Isn't it symmetric? By the way, in the second definition I presume $dx_I\wedge dx_J$ is defined by the concatenation $dx_{I,J}$?